# Does "group date" mean something else other than "a date with many people"?

Tags: japanese-language, steins-gate

In the first episode of *Steins;Gate 0*, Okarin says something about going on group dates, with Feyris and Rukako yelling at him for doing that.

Is a group date any different from what I think it is, just a date with many people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When asked by Feyris what Okarin's plan that day, he replied with "*gōkon*".

> Is a group date [...] a date with many people?

If "*a date*" implies "*those who are already in relationships*", then possibly this is the source of the misunderstanding.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_dating),

> **Group dating** is a modern pattern for dating where a group of single men and a group of single women organise a night out, with the hope of forming romantic partnerships. It is most popular in Japan, where it is known as *gōkon*. In other cultures, **group dating** is becoming more popular as a safe alternative to single dating (especially blind dating), also helping to ease tension, because both parties will feel more comfortable having the company of their friends.

Also,

> In Japan, a **gōkon** (合コン) is a group blind date, typically used to form at least some friendships between two groups that are each of a single sex. Generally, a single man and woman who know each other organize the *gōkon* in advance, each agreeing to bring three or four eligible friends. The venue is usually a restaurant, an izakaya, or anywhere people can eat, drink and make a bit of noise.

Or alternatively, from [Jisho](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%90%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3)

> joint party (e.g. by students from several colleges); combined party; mixer; two or more groups, esp. female and male students, combining for a party​

---

*However*, the real reason why Feyris and Rukako were yelling and surprised was

> Okarin's 180-degree image change. Compared to his [*chuunibyou*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8632/is-chuunibyou-syndrome-real)/*otaku* personality in the original *Steins;Gate*, he's now living (or looks) like a *normal* college student (i.e. having a social life, which is something that *otaku* usually don't care). Just before this, they were also surprised about his choice of school club ―which is tennis club― instead of Feyris' guess of UFO/UMA research club.

Comment: A better translation could perhaps be "mixer". At least that's what Black Clover subs used in ep 28.